# What is ̚▢p equal to in modal logic?

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I would assume  ̚▢p= ◇p v  ̚◇p, but I’m not sure.

Comment: ¬□p is equivalent to ◇¬p

Comment: @Bumble, please don't do kids' homework for them. It just encourages more questions like this that could be answered with two minutes of searching online.